# Refresh page php

Tags: php, refresh

how would i go about refreshing a page after i have submitted a form and done some php stuff with it. Heres my form and the php so far.

```
<form  class="removeform"action='peteadd.php'method='post' enctype='multipart/form-  
 data' name='image_remove_form' > 
    <?php
       include '../inc/connect.php';
       $q = "SELECT * FROM gallerythumbs WHERE gallery = 1";
       if($r = mysql_query($q)){
          while($row=mysql_fetch_array($r)){
             echo "<div class='thumb'>",
           "<input type='checkbox' name='remove[{$row['id']}]'>",
           "<label for='Remove'><span class='text'>Remove</span></label>",
           "<br />",
           "<img class='thumbnail' src='{$row['filename']}' 
                     alt='{$row['description']}' />",
        "</div>";
         }

     }
             else{
                echo mysql_error();
             }
         ?>
          <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Remove' />
          </form>
            </div>
            <?php
                 include '../inc/connect.php';
                 //if delete was checked, delete entries from both tables
                 if(isset($_POST['remove'])){
                    $chk = (array) $_POST['remove'];
                    $p = implode(',',array_keys($chk)); 
                    $t = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM galleryimages WHERE id IN ($p)");
                $r = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM gallerythumbs WHERE id IN ($p)");
                    $url=mysql_fetch_array($t);
                    $image=$url['filename'];
                    $url2=mysql_fetch_array($r);
                    $image2=$url2['filename'];    
                    if ($t){
                       unlink($image); 
               unlink($image2); 
                       $q = mysql_query("DELETE FROM galleryimages WHERE id IN ($p)");
                       $s = mysql_query("DELETE FROM gallerythumbs WHERE id IN ($p)");

                     }

                     else{
                        echo "<span class='text'>
                        There has been a problem, go back and try again.
                        <br />
                        <a href='peteadd.php'>Back</a>
                        </span>";
                     }
                }
                else{
                  echo "<span class='title'>
                        There are no images in the gallery
                        <br />
                        <a href='peteadd.php'>Add Images</a>
                        </span>";
                }
             ?>
```

This for display some thumbnails that are saved in mysql with a remove checkbox above them. When I check them then submit the form the are deleted from the direcotries and the mysql tables ok, but how can I refresh the page so the deletion is obvious?

Thanks for looking

Comment: Doesn't the page refresh when the form is submitted?

Comment: Maybe you need to rearrange your code. First check `$_POST` and  delete images. Next read gallery and print form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are describing sounds like you are displaying your page and within it you run some additional code - like deletion - so when you post your form you end up with images being pull from database and then removed

you should run your logic first and only then display page - that way you will be first deleting your records and then when it came to get data from database it will get right data (without records already deleted)

any other soultion will be nothing but hacky way to bypass problem that souldn't exist in the first place :)

Comment: thank you very much, by putting my logic first it worked as it should!

Comment: Can you help me with one more thing?

Comment: I changed my input from checkboxes to button above each image. But now it will delete the first image ok, but all further attempts to delete images bring up the 'browser needs to resend information' popup.

Comment: you must change request from post to get by simply redirect to the same page after deleting records - so after you delete just call "header('same_url'); exit();" and it should work - also redirect should go with 302 code

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly refresh a page with PHP, but you can echo out a refresh tag like this

```
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0">'
```

, or you can do it with javascript, like

```
location.reload(true);
```